# Question about the absolute convergence of a series

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

I've seen this property on my textbook, and I don't understand it.

If $a_n\ge 0 $  after a certain $v$ for all $n>v$
Then: $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|a_n|=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n$.
Can someone explain why this works?

Shouldn't it be $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|a_n|\ge\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n$$

Comment: Well agreed that as it stands it's nonsense. But your suggestion has the inequality the wrong way round. Can you give a name to the textbook, and edit to show *exactly* what the book says?

Comment: Well, it's actually in Italian, so I don't think it will help much

Comment: I think it should be only $a_n>0$

Comment: As amended it is correct: and in general you won't get equality unless $a_n\ge 0$ for all $n\ge 0$.

Comment: The inequality, $a_n>0$ after a certain $v$,I think it should only be $a_n>0$ if that makes sense

Comment: Can you please give the name, author and page number of your textbook? (and/or a screenshot) Whatever the language, it *will* help.

Comment: I can't do that, it's my teacher book for the course and I don't want to make any names.

Comment: Also I made an edit to the post, idk if it makes any difference. ( I added for all $n>v$)

Comment: So it is not a "real" book? (i.e. published, publicly availabe)

Comment: No, it's only for the students.

Comment: Well, point that probable mistake to your teacher, if (s)he really wrote that, (s)he should be grateful and correct it.

Comment: @Randomdude where do you study?

Comment: @SineoftheTime I'm studying at Sapienza

Comment: @Randomdude Good university :). Keep going

Comment: The amended inequality is true as long as both sides converge (i.e. they are well defined), the condition given isn't relevant.

Comment: The amended inequality is true even if one or both sides diverge. The LHS is always defined (as an element of $[0,+\infty]$). Similarly, thanks to condition given, the RHS is (possibly $+\infty$ but) defined.